# Container height change makes children shake in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, height, shake

I created this effect on the top image , it sticks to the top while scrolling and hide... this is the the site:
[The site](http://glhomes.co.uk/development.php?id=13)

so it works great on chrome , firefox but in safari the image inside the container shakes, i tried with float left , also tried setting the top and left values to 0 but it still shakes... 
anyone has an idea what's the problem ?

css code:

```
.devBigImage {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.devBigImage img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS code:

```
        var imageHeight = $('.devBigImage').height(),
        imageMarginBottom = $('.devBigImage').css('margin-bottom').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');

    $(document).on({
        scroll: function() {
            if ($('.devBigImage').length>0) {

                var iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

                    if (imageHeight - iCurScrollPos > 0) {
                        $('.devBigImage').css({
                            'height':imageHeight - iCurScrollPos,
                            'position':'relative',
                            'top':iScrollPos,
                            'margin-bottom':iScrollPos+parseInt(imageMarginBottom),
                        });
                    }

            }
        }
    });
```

html:

```
    <div class="devBigImage">
    <img src="http://www.get-covers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Colorful-Stripes.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an all css javascript-free solution?

You can create a div with position 'fixed' which means relative to the window, and make that div have a z-index of -1, this way the rest of the page content will be on top.

Then you just need some kind of a transparent placeholder div so when the page first loads the transparent div will hold the top position, showing the underlying logo.

As you scroll the page the transparent div scrolls up, while the fixed position div stays in place in the background

```
#background-logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;    
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1
}
#hidden-background-logo-placeholder img{
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
}
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb0umfy3/)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27t4xhgn/), which works fine in Safari, though I had to change iScrollPos to iCurScrollPos to make it work. I think the problem is with the relative position which is costly on CPU. Also please try methods like storing found jQuery DOM objects in a variable, so that they don't need to be searched on DOM repetitively.

```
var bigTmageDiv = $('.devBigImage');
var imageHeight = bigTmageDiv.height(),
    imageMarginBottom = bigTmageDiv.css('margin-bottom').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');

$(document).on({
    scroll: function() {
        if (bigTmageDiv.length>0) {

            var iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

                if (imageHeight - iCurScrollPos > 0) {
                    $('.devBigImage').css({
                        'height':imageHeight - iCurScrollPos,
                        'position':'relative',
                        'top':iScrollPos,
                        'margin-bottom':iScrollPos+parseInt(imageMarginBottom),
                    });
                }

        }
    }
});
```

Hope this solves the problem or at least optimize your code a bit.